# Missing font in ubuntu (SimSun)

Tags: fonts, xetex, ubuntu

Previously I complied my file using Xelatex in window 7 using Miktex and it works fine. Now I install TexLive 2009 in Ubuntu 12.04 and compile the same file again, but the following error occurs after compilation (`xelatex myfile.tex`):

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf SimSun
! I can't find file `SimSun'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: SimSun.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun' failed to make SimSun.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \zf@basefont=SimSun at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or install
ed font not found.
<to be read again> 
               \let 
l.30 \setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
Set Chinese font, complusory
?
```

Is there any way I can use the font available for MikTex in Window 7 from Ubuntu? or any other way to deal with it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=kaiming,CJKspace=true,CheckSingle=true} 

\begin{document}
宋體中文字
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can copy any font file that you have access to to your `$HOME/.fonts` directory. `XeLaTeX` will find any fonts in there.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where can I access my font file in Window and copy to the $HOME/.fonts directory? And which directory should I put in the Ubuntu? I am still new to Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want them system wide you can put them in /usr/share/fonts. I'm not sure what command you have to run afterwards. Perhaps `fc-cache -fsv`? Note that in the future if you want everything taken care of automatically and are installing from scratch, you can run `sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --usr-fonts-dir <DIR>` where <DIR> contains the files simhei.ttf and simsun.ttc. For more information, see https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: I downloaded the font from http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/SimSun/, installed it in a usual way (alternatively, I could use a working directory with your MWE TeX file included without system font installation), swapped a pair of letters, `docuemnt` -> `document`, and your example has been typeset successfully with XeLaTeX (Windows XP, TeXLive 2013).

Comment: Windows: search for file `SimSun.ttf` with the windows explorer (is this how it is called?). Or, alternatively, download the file from the internet as Malipivo says. The `$HOME/.fonts` part refers to the Ubuntu installation. In Ubuntu, open the folder explorer, go to your home folder, and on the `View` menu check the `Show hidden files` option. Then you can acces the `.fonts` directory and copy `SimSun.ttf` here.

Comment: I copied the `simsun.ttc` from Window (in the Font folder) and put it in the same directory, `xelatex myfile.tex`, but I still get the same error.  (Thanks @Malipivo to point out my typo) Also I cannot find the `.fonts` directory as mentioned by @guillem , only `.fontconfig`.

Comment: @jc2254 You are welcome. In case you are using working directory, send the xelatex+fontspec packages all the information, just to be sure: `\setCJKmainfont[ExternalLocation=./]{SimSun.ttf}`. The problem I had in the past was related to the first run of XeLaTeX. It was generating information to the cache directory and it took several minutes on the first run. We can run it manually, e.g. by using `fc-cache -fv` as it was mentioned by scottkosty earlier.

Comment: @Malipivo I add the `\setCJKmainfont[ExternalLocation=./]{SimSun.ttc}` but it got the following error: `(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty)kpathsea: Invalid fontname [./SimSun', contains '['`

Comment: @jc2254 I downloaded a ttc version from `http://code.google.com/p/way2ctx/downloads/detail?name=simsun.ttc` just to cover everything. And I think I emulated your problem, because `\setCJKmainfont[ExternalLocation=./]{SimSun.ttc}` is not working for me as I used capital letters in the name of the file, but this `\setCJKmainfont[ExternalLocation=./]{simsun.ttc}` is working. It is case sensitive in Lubuntu, but not in Windows XP. Please try it.

Comment: @Malipivo After changing to match the case, it works! You can mention this procedure in the answer so I can accept it. I will look up more information about font and Ubuntu later to make things working globally, but now the working directory method is ok for me (now just want to focus on the document first) .

Comment: @jc2254 After installing/moving font(s) to the system font directory, try to delete `[ExternalLocation=./]` in that command and delete/move that font in/from the working directory. XeLaTeX shall find the font among system fonts automatically.

Comment: I have the exact same problem:  using Ubuntu, installed TexLive-full, but always got the font-not-found error.  Tried spelling, etc.  I have put the fonts in the current directory as well as in ~/.fonts.  Run mktexlsr and also fc-cache -fsv, also texhash.  When I do fc-list :lang=zh-cn I can see the fonts SimSun etc.  But xelatex always complain it cannot find the font(s).  :(

Comment: Oh, I found out the reason:  File permissions.  I have to `sudo chmod a+rw` for the font files.

Comment: This web page (in Chinese) covers a lot of useful information:
https://wrjih.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/latex%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E7%9A%84%E5%8F%A6%E4%B8%80%E5%80%8B%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F-xelatex-for-chinese-windows-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that filenames are case sensitive in (L)ubuntu, but they are not in Windows (XP). When moving from Windows to Ubuntu, this problem arised.